# Writing into a file using two threads

Tags: c++, windows, operating-system

I'm trying to put together a program that uses threads and file functions , this is the code

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <mutex>
using namespace std;

//global handle for semaphore and mutex and file
HANDLE hsemaphore;
HANDLE hmutex;
int i = 1;
fstream FileX( "FileX.txt");

//thread function
DWORD WINAPI MySyncFun(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    while (i <= 20) {
        
            WaitForSingleObject(hsemaphore, INFINITE);
            WaitForSingleObject(hmutex, INFINITE); //mutex lock

            FileX << "count-" << i++ << endl;

            ReleaseMutex(hmutex); //mutex unlock
            ReleaseSemaphore(hsemaphore, 1, 0);
        }
    
    return 0;
}
int main()
{
    //local variable
    HANDLE hthread1;
    HANDLE hthread2;

    //step 1 create semaphore
    hsemaphore = CreateSemaphore(
        NULL,
        2,
        2,
        NULL);
    if (NULL == hsemaphore) {
        cout << "semaphore creation failed & error No- " << GetLastError() << endl;
    }
    cout << "semaphore creation success" << endl;

    //step 2 mutex creation
    hmutex = CreateMutex(
        NULL,
        FALSE,
        NULL);
    if (NULL == hmutex) {
        cout << "mutex creation failed & error no- " << GetLastError() << endl;
    }
    cout << "mutex creation success" << endl;

FileX.open("FileX.txt", ios::out);
Char ch;
If(!FileX)
{ Cout<<"file not created"<< endl; }
    //step 3 create 2 threads
    hthread1 = CreateThread(
        NULL,
        0,
        &MySyncFun,
        NULL,
        0,
        0);

    hthread2 = CreateThread(
        NULL,
        0,
        &MySyncFun,
        NULL,
        0,
        0);

    //step 4 wait for single object for all threads
    WaitForSingleObject(hthread1, INFINITE);
    WaitForSingleObject(hthread2, INFINITE);

    //close handle for threads
    CloseHandle(hthread1);
    CloseHandle(hthread2);

    //close handle for the mutex
    CloseHandle(hmutex);

    //close handle for the semaphore
    CloseHandle(hsemaphore);

    //Opening the file to show its content
    FileX.open("FileX.txt", ios::out);
    char ch;
    if (!FileX) {
        cout << "file not created!" << endl;
    }
    else {
        while (1) {
            FileX >> ch;
            if (FileX.eof())
                break;
            cout << ch;
            FileX.close();
        }
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

The file is created , but the while loop part doesn't print out the contents of char ch.

The point of this code is to have two threads writing stuff in a text file and then reading the text file content into console.

Comment: A file stream object can only be opened once before being closed. A second open automatically fails and puts the stream into a fail state to force you to deal with it. You want one file stream and one open. Consider replacing `fstream FileX;` with `fstream FileX("FileX.txt", ios::in)` and removing the calls to open. Also try to avoid global variables where possible. Consider making a structure to hold the file stream and synchronization objects, allocating that structure in `main`, and passing it into the threads as the user argument.

Comment: @user4581301 I've tried using fstream FileX("FileX.txt", ios::in) , but it only gives the error that ios is not declared . I also would rather keep atleast one open function for later purposes

Comment: Then open it once in `main` before creating the threads, and close once after waiting for them to finish.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik it worked thank you , but still the second part of printing the contents of fileX after writing to it isn't woking . It gives no error though.

Comment: You open the file for writing (`ios::out`), but are trying to read from it.